# Faking item changes in Dspace

Tags: dspace

I have a particular situation with the dspace I am running. I need to fake that some update have happen on an item so this would trigger a re-harvesting via the OAI protocol.

What would be the best way to do that ? Shall I reach the database directly and change the last modified value myself or can i do a context commit on an object without doing anything on it.

I just want to make sure that an external repository that consume item from an internal dspace repo, get to do it automatically periodically on all the item of the internal repo even if no changes have happened.

Answer (score 1):

**To prepare a collection for the initial harvest**, you need to ensure that the collection items are available to the OAI service.

If you change an item (by any method), run

```
.../bin/dspace oai import
.../bin/dspace oai clean-cache
```

The commands listed above should be scheduled in your cron.

For testing purposes, run the following to force everything to refresh

```
.../bin/dspace oai import -c
.../bin/dspace oai clean-cache
```

In the OAI SOLR repository, the item will look like this.

```
  {
    "item.id": 858,
    "item.public": true,
    "item.handle": "10822/761511",
    "item.lastmodified": "2016-04-15T23:25:13.321Z",
    "item.submitter": "user@org.edu",
    "item.deleted": false,
    "item.collections": [
      "col_10822_552792"
    ],
    "item.communities": [
      "com_10822_707896",
      "com_10822_707878",
      "com_10822_1"
    ],
    ...
}
```

**To harvest updates from your collection**

Once you have established a harvested collection, the harvester will continue to poll the source collection for updates.

These updates are based on the item.lastmodified date.  You must trigger an update to the item.lastmodified date to trigger the re-harvesting of an item.

Comment: What would be the difference between making a metadata update on my all repository and running /bin/dspace oai import ? and simply running /bin/dspace oai import -c ? In particular with respect to OAI Solr index ?

Comment: How does the OAI Solr index related to the Solr index where item are actually indexed. What i usually do for a full refresh is that i empty the collection in the admin interface and then relaunch a harvest ? how does that relate to the command you have just described to me ?

Comment: What ultimately i would like to do is to avoid to empty the collection and simply update

Comment: oai import pulls any updates since the last time "oai import" was run.  "oai import -c" rebuilds the entire index from every item.  The "-c" option is generally run when rebuilding or upgrading a system. If your destination collection is harvesting based on a date, your approach of modifying the update date on each item is likely to appear as new content.  The "clean-cache" forces the cache to be rebuilt and ensures that you are harvesting the most recent changes.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by <<If your destination collection is harvesting based on a date, your approach of modifying the update date on each item is likely to appear as new content>>  I thought that <<oai import pulls any updates since the last time "oai import" was run>> is actually based on the dates of the last update, if it is supperior to the last oai import then i update the item, otherwise no. So i do not get the first point. I'm sorry but i need pedagogy on this

Comment: @maatdeamon, I have updated the answer to address the additional discussion in the comments.

Comment: Hey @terrywb, thanks that helps a little. So basically, my idea to go trough the database automatically was wrong. The information that you show above is information in solr. So I must i must actually use the Dspace api to get the item and fake an update. Or else using the -c option in the receiving repository ? This will somewhat trigger the same consequence. I mean, how granular is the update ? does the item in the source OAI index get fully re-index in the target OAI index, or it is much more granular in term of what is copied ? What would you go for ?

Comment: On one side, i would have to go trough all the item of my repository and do some form of update operation that changes nothing for instance replacing a metadata value by itself, or simply have a cron job, that does oai import -c, this on a weekly bases, let say every sunday.

Comment: My suggestion of running "import -c" may have been a distraction. oai import -c just refreshes the OAI repository.  Items will be recreated with the same modification date.  If you want the item modification date to be updated, you must modify the item and trigger a change to its modification date. You could do this manually, via the dspace api, or one of the command line tools such as ItemUpdate.  If you run "oai import" regularly, you should not need to run "oai import -c".

Comment: There is a background story to that that is a bit complex to explain. But to keep the story short, the system has been badly connected to a Thesaurus server, which has resulted in change in the thesaurus, not implying change in the record. Because what is in the record both in value and authority is actually the Ids' of the thesaurus term/concept. So given that there is an external repo that consume from that internal repo, we want a way for that external repo to consume changes. Hence i need to fake that something has change for force a re-harvesting.

Comment: The harvesting process had been modified to fetch information from the thesaurus server. That's the background story. I inherited the system and the owner wants a quick fix. So final questions: Does import -c, clean the search collection too and the database ? if not then i might just use that isn't it. On the other hand, going for faking a change on the item directly, can i add some info, then remove it and then commit, will that count has an item s been modified or not ? Otherwise, just for faking that change i will have to commit twice, had something commit and remove something commit !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111815/discussion-between-terrywb-and-maatdeamon).